# Проверка на выбор варианта

Tags: jquery

Парни, привет.

Задача: проверить выбор варианта в миникарточке товара, если вариант не выбран, выводит сообщение "Выберите вариант".

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item__variant">
            <div class="item__variant-1"></div>
            <div class="item__variant-2"></div>
            <div class="item__variant-3"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="item__add-to-cart">Купить</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item__variant">
            <div class="item__variant-1"></div>
            <div class="item__variant-2"></div>
            <div class="item__variant-3"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="item__add-to-cart">Купить</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.item__add-to-cart').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this).siblings('.item__variant');

    if(!$($this).find('active')) {

        alert("Выберите вариант");

    }
});
```

jQuery не работает...

Answer (score 3):

вероятно вы хотели найти элемент у которого установлен класс `active`, однако в коде поиск элемента `<active>`. Для указания класса в селекторе jquery используйте `.active`.

```
var $this = $(this).siblings('.item__variant');
if(!$this.find('.active')) {
    alert("Выберите вариант");
}
```

также отмечу лишнюю обертку `$($this)`, достаточно простого `$this`, ибо это и так уже переменная jquery.

Comment: да и вообще плодить переменные, если один раз пользуешься, не стоит - достаточно `if(!$(this).siblings('.item__variant').find('.active'))`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev в переменной в целом ничего плохого нет, зона ее видимости/жизни  ограничена. Можно и без них, но это на любителя, длинные выражения тоже не всегда удобны. Однако, использование имени переменной `$this`  вообще сомнительно, так как потенциально может привести к путанице и ошибкам, когда этот `$this` спутают простым `this`